# How to paralellize a simple function with Dask and Arima?

Tags: python, dask, arima

I am trying to paralellize a simple function with Dask to try make things faster... but I am struggling very much! Could anyone help? This is my current code:

```
order_aic_bic=[]

@delayed
def test(df):
    model = ARIMA(df, order=(p, d, q))
    results = model.fit()
    return results

for p in range(10):
    for q in range(10):
        try:
            a = test(ir)
            order_aic_bic.append((p, d, q, a.aic, a.bic))
        except:
            print(p, d, q, None, None)

graph = delayed()(order_aic_bic)
lst = graph.compute()
```

The code above gives a warning/error **"warnings.warn(Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "** and takes even longer than original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to pass `p, d, q` explicitly to the `test` function. Otherwise, I don't think there is a guarantee that they will use appropriate values.

Also, `try/except` block was not needed, since lazy values would always be returned and the except block will not be called (in practice, you were trying to get `.aic` from a lazy module, so that would lead to an error, but if your `try` block did not contain that error, then `try/except` are not needed).

```py
from dask import delayed, compute

@delayed(nout=2)
def test(df, p, d, q):
    model = ARIMA(df, order=(p, d, q))
    results = model.fit()
    return results.aic, results.bic


order_aic_bic = []

for p in range(10):
    for q in range(10):
        a = test(ir)
        order_aic_bic.append((p, d, q, *a))

final = compute(order_aic_bic)
```

Comment: That makes sense... passing the arguments to the test function! Also, great to hear I don't need to use try/except for lazy values... it also makes sense. Thanks!